# Implementing a custom DataReader class with static method utilizing BufferedReader

Tags: java, backend

I'm looking to implement a small app for a recruitment task and I started wondering about good practices.

The Main.class instantiates a IntegerProcessor.class. The IntegerProcessor does all of the work for my task, and should collect input from the System.in.

I use BufferedReader for that. I am really confused now, is it a good practice to use it from a static context. Of course it's a small app, however my current mentor always emphasizes that we should use static methods ONLY when we are sure it's safe and avoid using it for reading data (DB connections, file reading, etc).

Am I taking the wrong approach here?

EDIT:
I am also considering that it would be hard to test/mock the DataReader since it's static.

Thank you.

```
List<Integer> integersFromInput = DataReader.readIntegersFromInput();
// process the collection
```

```
        List<Integer> numbers = new ArrayList<>();

        try (BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in))) {


            String line;

            System.out.println("Please enter integers: ");
            while ((line = br.readLine()) != null && line.length() > 0) {
                String[] strNumbers = line.split("\\s+");
                for (String strNumber : strNumbers) {
                    numbers.add(Integer.parseInt(strNumber));
                }
            }


            if (numbers.isEmpty()){
                throw new IllegalArgumentException("You haven't entered any integers!");
            }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suppose that you are returning "numbers" to the caller. In this case, using a static method is an appropriate approach as you are not saving any state into the object, nor using any instance variables: your method is self contained in terms of state. However, if you were using a database connection, as you mentioned as example, using an instance method would allow you to save the connection parameters in the object and be able to have different instances for that, based on environment, for example.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I'm thinking this way now: we have only one STDIN, therefore it's impossible to make the reader "confused". If we would read from a file, there is the possibility that the method would be triggered more than once at the same time (eg. read from two different files) and the data could interfere between two streams in the same instance. Is that the case here as well?